# Escaping quotes in javascript variable placed in function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping, quotes

I have in my html an edit image with:

```
 onclick="javascript:editBook(author,title)"
```

author and title are variables containing values from a PHP script. And editBook is a function to open a new window where to edit the author and title of the book.

title may contain a title with quotes and when the title contains quotes it causes an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" error when clicked.

What do I have to do to escape the quotes in the book title?

Apart from quotes, there are another symbols like & that a book's title can contain. How can I escape that too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the PHP script:

```
function javascript_escape($string) 
{ 
    return str_replace("\n", '\n', str_replace('"', '\"', addcslashes(str_replace("\r", '', (string)$string), "\0..\37'\\"))); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the backslash character `\` the key above enter

reference http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp

Comment: I cannot see any chapter about quotes inside a variable and how to escape them. Please tell me if you find it. Thanks

Comment: Going by your edited answer it looks like you want to concatenate. So if author and title are variables do this `onclick="javascript:editBook(" + author + "," + title + ")"`